# Load resource dictionary in wpf add in application

Tags: resources, outlook-addin

Hi i need to make multilingual WPF office add-in. I want to use resources files. i call in my ThisAddIn_Startup function my SetLanguageDictionary

```
 public static void SetLanguageDictionary()
    {
        try
        {
        //Get the assembly information
        System.Reflection.Assembly assemblyInfo = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Uri uriCodeBase = new Uri(assemblyInfo.CodeBase);
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(uriCodeBase.LocalPath.ToString());

        ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();

        switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString())
        {
            case "en-US":
                dict.Source = new Uri(path + "\\Resources\\en-US.xaml",
                              UriKind.Absolute);
                break;
            case "fr-FR":
                dict.Source = new Uri(path + "\\Resources\\fr-FR.xaml",
                              UriKind.Absolute);
                break;
            default:
                dict.Source = new Uri(path + "\\Resources\\en-US.xaml",
                              UriKind.Absolute);
                break;
        }

            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

my resources files are there

```
<ResourceDictionary 
      xmlns ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
      xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <system:String x:Key="Ready">Ready</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="login">Login</system:String>
    <!-- All StringResources Goes Here -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

when loading i have the error :
System invalid operation exception : operation error loadfrom resouceDictionary with URI:"file:///c:

thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. It s just because load of resourcesdictionary could only be done by code behind xaml page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert in File App.xaml the direction of your files.. in my case for example:

```
<Application x:Class="VBControl.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VBControl"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\StringResources.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\StringResources.en-EN.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\StringResources.pt-BR.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```